# App crash when adding item to ListView

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-listview

I have a `ListView` that seems to crash on certain occasions when I'm adding an item to it.
The worst thing about this crash is that I can't find consistent reproduction steps. It always happens upon having a new item added to the `ListView` but it only happens once for every ~10 item adds.

I have a real-time client that keeps getting data added to it over time. When I have two devices showing the same data getting a new one together and one of them crashes, the other one crashes too for the same reason.

This is the stacktrace and error:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: {packagename}, PID: 28309
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4309)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4145)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4086)
    at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager.addView(ReactViewManager.java:203)
    at com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewManager.addView(ReactViewManager.java:37)
    at com.facebook.react.uimanager.NativeViewHierarchyManager.manageChildren(NativeViewHierarchyManager.java:394)
```

I couldn't find anyone with this issue in react-native that doesn't relate to his own native code. I didn't write any native code in this one.

According to posts about this issue for native Android apps, it smells like the `ListView` somehow mishandling it's items and trying to add one before detaching it from a previous parent.

Does anyone have ideas about what might cause it?
Thanks.

#### Update:

Here's my code, it's longer than needed for the example but just in case it contains something weird I'm doing that causes this issue, I'm attaching the whole thing

```
class ItemsViewer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this._isMounted = true;
        const dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
        this.state = {
          dataSource: dataSource,
        };

        this._shouldAdjustScrollForKeyboardOnNextLayout = false;

        this._scrollListToBottomThrottled = throttle(this._scrollListToBottom.bind(this), 300);
        this._onListLayout = this._onListLayout.bind(this);
        this._onFooterLayout = this._onFooterLayout.bind(this);
        this._renderRow = this._renderRow.bind(this);
        this._renderFooter = this._renderFooter.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;
        this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.props.items)});
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.items != nextProps.items) {
            this.setState({dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(nextProps.items)});
        }

        if(this.props.isKeyboardShown != nextProps.isKeyboardShown) {
            this._shouldAdjustScrollForKeyboardOnNextLayout = true;
        }
    }

    _scrollListToBottom() {
        if(!this._isMounted) return;

        if (this.listHeight && this.footerY && this.footerY > this.listHeight) {
            var scrollTarget = this.listHeight - this.footerY;
            var scrollResponder = this.refs.itemsList.getScrollResponder();

            scrollResponder.scrollTo({y: -scrollTarget});
        }
    }

    _onScroll(event) {
        this.scrollY = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
    }

    _renderRow(rowData, sectionID, rowID) {
        let prevItem = null;
        if(this.props.items.length > 1 && rowID > 0) {
            prevItem = this.props.items[rowID - 1];
        }

        return renderItem(getItemByContentType, rowData, prevItem, this.props.userColor);
    }

    _onListLayout(event) {
        this.prevListHeight = this.listHeight === undefined ? 0 : this.listHeight;
        this.listHeight = event.nativeEvent.layout.height;

        this._adjustScrollForKeyboardIfNeeded();
    }

    _adjustScrollForKeyboardIfNeeded() {
        if(!this._isMounted) return;
        
        if(!this._shouldAdjustScrollForKeyboardOnNextLayout) return;
        this._shouldAdjustScrollForKeyboardOnNextLayout = false;

        const diff = this.prevListHeight - this.listHeight;
        var scrollTarget = this.scrollY + diff;
        this.refs.itemsList.scrollTo({y: scrollTarget});
    }

    _onFooterLayout(event) {
        const prevY = this.footerY;
        this.footerY = event.nativeEvent.layout.y + event.nativeEvent.layout.height;

        // Scrolling to bottom when footer location has changed, indicating new items arrived
        if(this.footerY !== prevY) {
            this._scrollListToBottomThrottled();
        }
    }

    _renderFooter() {
        return <View onLayout={this._onFooterLayout}
                     style={style.listFooter} />;
    }

    render() {
        const {dataSource} = this.state;

        return <ListView dataSource={dataSource} enableEmptySections={true}
                         renderRow={this._renderRow}
                         ref='itemsList' initialListSize={50}
                         onLayout={this._onListLayout}
                         renderFooter={this._renderFooter}
                         onScroll={this._onScroll.bind(this)} />;
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you use adapter for your listView ? Can you show code ?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by adapter so probably not. Added the code.

Comment: The error suggests the item you are adding, is already added to somewhere else. You cannot add it to two different things.

Comment: What are you trying to return inside render row ?

Comment: When you set the state initially in your constructor, try passing an empty array to your data source and see if that fixes things. this.state = { dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithRows([]) };

Comment: `Doomsknight` - It's an Android error, more chances that it's a bug with react-native/ListView native code.
@Codesingh It calls a separate function that simply creates react elements, it has no cache or something that may use the same rendered instances.
`AlexHarrison` - My initial data before items arrive is an empty array

Comment: rather then calling on return inside renderRow try something different like return a view with text or do one thing add code of renderitem function.

Comment: @Codesingh Since this is hard to reproduce it would be hard to tell if it helped, can you elaborate why you think having a separate function for that render may cause an issue? It doesn't make any sense to me unless you meant to tell me to just test a simpler view for my items to see what happens then.

Comment: did you try simpler view on your renderRow then we will judge what's the problem